# How to port docker to arm aarch64

Tags: linux, docker, arm

I am interested to run docker on Arm aarch64 board, I would like to isolate few applications/binaries (written in c) using the docker container, all of them running in the same docker container, all the apps use the internet for communication with the server.

I am unable to find with google search,  a proper way to cross compile docker for arm and create images for arm, I see that the main focus is x86 to deploy the apps. It would be a great help, if  someone can point me to some good tutorials or things to be downloaded and built for arm. Thank You

Comment: I could swear there is already docker for ARM. Could you be more specific about what is exactly your problem?

Comment: i do not really know where to start, I am new to the containers. when you say "there is docker for arm", it works on any linux kernel running on arm ? I am using a custom board with Yocto Poky Embedded Linux